# element not set with try catch in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am writing a protractor testscript for my angular js webapplication. There is a jsonfile that  I am using to fill in the data on the page. The try statement will look for the element that has the model property:

```
   var data = {name: 'James', address: '11 Sussex street'};

   for (key in data) {
            try {
                var el = element(by.model('name'));
                if (el.isElementPresent()) {
                    el.clear().sendKeys(data[key]);
                }

            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log('error occured', err);
            }
        }
```

When I run the test now I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findElementsOverride' of undefined
```

The name element is present but does not get set?

Comment: Why don't you first verify with `element(locator).isElementPresent()`

Comment: I did but the value still does not get set?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
var el = element(by.model('name'));
el.isPresent().then(function(present) {
  if (present) {
    el.clear().sendKeys('James');
  }
}).catch(err) {
  console.log('error occured', err);
}
```